# Button Click Does not works without Keyboard/Human interruption

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ui-automation, keyboard-events

Scenario: Developer generates JWT Token by calling external services and after generating jwt, it copies and paste in authorize section of Swagger and click authorize button,and after that we can fire the API from swagger as it have jwt token now.

I have tried to automate it, As soon as JWT is generated My JS code will enter the jwt token in authorize section and tries to click authorize button.But There is some issue here, I can see that JS is trying to click authorize button(In Console I can see the action) but nothing is happening. I also noticed that if we add anything manually from keyboard, and then press button it works. How do I simulate this in JS?

Note: If we press/enter any character from keyboard manually and then trigger z.click() it works ? How can we simulate keyboard press on input text in JS ?

I tried this, but did not worked:

```
 document.getElementById("va").dispatchEvent(
 new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
 key: "e",
 keyCode: 69, // example values.
 code: "KeyE", // put everything you need in this object.
 which: 69,
 shiftKey: false, // you don't need to include values
 ctrlKey: false,  // if you aren't going to use them.
 metaKey: false   // these are here for example's sake.
 })
);



 const txtToken = document.getElementById("jwttoken");

function simulateEnterToken (x,tokens){
var val=x.getElementsByClassName("dialog-ux")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-inner")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-content")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("auth-container")[0] .getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[1];
   val.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id="va";
  document.getElementById("va").value=tokens;

 console.log(x);
}


function simulateClickAuthorize(x){
 var y=x.getElementsByClassName("dialog-ux")[0]
         .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux")[0]
          .getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog-ux")[0]
          .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-inner")[0]
          .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-content")[0]
         .getElementsByClassName("auth-container")[0]
          .getElementsByClassName("auth-btn-wrapper")[0];
           console.log(y);
       var z=y.getElementsByClassName("btn modal-btn auth authorize button")[0];
   z.click();
    }
```

Added 2 Screenshots for clear understanding

[image]

[image]

Note : I have also tried to simulate keyboard events

```
document.getElementById("va").value.dispatchEvent(new 
KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));


 document.getElementById("va").dispatchEvent(
 new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
  key: "e",
  keyCode: 69, // example values.
  code: "KeyE", // put everything you need in this object.
  which: 69,
  shiftKey: false, // you don't need to include values
  ctrlKey: false,  // if you aren't going to use them.
  metaKey: false   // these are here for example's sake.
  })
 );
```

Also I cannot change anything from swagger as it is 3rd party library!

Edit: Output Of Console.log(z) attached

[image: Output Of Console.log(z)]
[image: Form Dont have ID]
EDIT 2:  Form Dont have ID

EDIT 3: @Roger Asked to submit the form

```
var val=x.getElementsByClassName("dialog-ux")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-inner")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-content")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("auth-container")[0]

val.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit()
```

It also did not worked , I got error page

Error

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.Mon Jul 20 14:01:11 IST 2020
> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Required String parameter 'product' is not present

EDIT 4: This is my initial URL

> http://localhost:8080/docs?product=test&docid=testapp-swagger-openapi&type=yaml#/person-controller/getPersonUsingGET

After clicking submit() the url is below with error

> http://localhost:8080/docs?#/person-controller/getPersonUsingGET

Image/network console after clicking submit()

[image: After clicking submit() programatically]

Note: There is no api call when we click manually

Comment: What does `console.log(z)` return?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have attached the output of console.log(z) in EDIT

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit your form, I believe you will want to target your form element and call the `submit` method.

Example (*assuming only a single `<form>` element is on the page*):

```
var formElement = document.getElementByTagName('form')[0];
formElement.submit();
```

Comment: So i need to get id of the form and submit right ? But The form doesnt have id , I have attached the screenshot in EDIT2

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to target the form element using `document.getElementByTagName`.

Comment: I managed to get the form and tried to submit , it returned error.I have added the error in question EDIT   var val=x.getElementsByClassName("dialog-ux")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-dialog-ux")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-inner")[0]
              .getElementsByClassName("modal-ux-content")[0]
             .getElementsByClassName("auth-container")[0]

val.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit().

Comment: Judging by the error message, it looks like you might be correctly calling your form's handler, but there is an error being thrown within the handler.

Comment: But when I do it manually(with my hands) I mean when i enter something in input text and press authorize it doesnot gives error, are we missing something?

Comment: I'd compare how the network calls look in you network tab (in your browser's developer console) and see how the API calls differ when submitting the form programatically vs manually.

Comment: When we click manually , network console is empty , and when we click programatically there is a network call.I have attached in EDIT4

Comment: After clicking submit , the url also changes from http://localhost:8080/docs?product=test&docid=testapp-swagger-openapi&type=yaml#/person-controller/getPersonUsingGET  to  http://localhost:8080/docs?#/person-controller/getPersonUsingGET

Comment: Robert: One more thing, when we press/enter any value from character value from keyboard and then trigger z.click() it works , can we simulate this ?

Comment: ON a input text can we simulate keyboard press?

Comment: `ON a input text can we simulate keyboard press?` not really but you can `.focus()`

Comment: document.getElementById("va").focus() tried this, but dint worked

Comment: @DarrenSweeney There might be some change Event Getting generated when user enters input from keyboard, I tried to dispatch that as well manually , but didnt worked